# Slow Loading Forms (submission ok)

Tags: forms

Hello i was wondering if anyone could suggest anything for me with this problem i have with my forms. (add/node) Ive turned CCK and all my modules off but still when i go to the node/add page the form is taking ages to load (20secs+) even for a simple submission form with no fields etc.

Generally my website http://onlinebanter.com runs ok and i do my best to keep my module lust down.

Is there any code or diagnostic tools i could use to see why my forms are talking so long to load.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was because i was using an old version of pressflow it must have had some security problems with the other modules. Updated and things running like a dream :)